# How is R used with ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, r

How is R used with ArcGIS for Desktop?

I have seen posts talking about combining rasters while using R.

I have not had much experience with R so not 100% certain of its capabilities.

I had thought that R was a scripting language for data analysis with tabulated data and data bases, but its seems much more than that.

Are there particular R libraries to incorporate it with ArcGIS for Desktop?

Comment: https://r-arcgis.github.io/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something very similar came up in the [GIS Chat Room yesterday](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/22747915#22747915) where @Kersten suggested reviewing [Integrating external programs within ModelBuilder](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//002w0000007w000000):

> This section describes how to integrate R, an external statistical
>   package, within the ModelBuilder environment. In the example described
>   below, there are two scripts needed to execute R functionality: a
>   Python script that calls the R source code and the actual R source
>   code. The Python script is what is called from ModelBuilder and serves
>   as a conduit, essentially organizing and piping the arguments from
>   ModelBuilder to R.

and I responded with:

- Take Away 10 from [The Top 11 Takeaways from the Esri Developer Summit](http://www.esri.com/esri-news/arcwatch/0515/the-top-11-takeaways-from-the-esri-developer-summit):

> With ArcGIS 10.3.1 for Desktop and ArcGIS Pro 1.1 (both currently
>   scheduled for release during the second quarter of 2015), you will be
>   able to run your native R scripts directly as script tools and allow R
>   to access ArcGIS data. Using the geoprocessing framework, your R
>   script will work directly with Esri-supported feature data, honoring
>   its selection and projection.

- [Esri and the Scientific Community: An Esri® White Paper: July 2015](http://www.esri.com/library/whitepapers/pdfs/esri-and-the-scientific-community.pdf) which says on p.4:

> A new open-source bridge library on GitHub will allow users of recent
>   versions of ArcGIS for Desktop and ArcGIS Pro to directly build R into
>   their workflows and to pass data between ArcGIS and R.

Comment: I have been alpha testing the ESRI bridge and it is fairly useful both in passing data back-and-forth but also in running R as an inline process. Toolbox scripts are easy to deploy where R function calls are as simple as (in.parm, out.parm).

Comment: Does anyone know of tutorials for the R bridge?